# Why dart infers the variable type as a int when I explicitly say the type is double?

Tags: dart

Here is the example from the [doc](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#numbers)

The doc says the
Integer literals are automatically converted to doubles when necessary:

```
double z = 1; // Equivalent to double z = 1.0.
```

But when I check the `runtimeType` the type is `int`

```
print(z.runtimeType); // prints to int
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are testing using dartpad.dev or compiled your code to JavaScript. In JavaScript, there are no separate types of `int` and `double` so Dart are just guessing the type, when using `runtimeType`, based on the current value since JavaScript are representing all numbers as `double` internally.

But if we are running in the Dart VM or compiled to native code, we can determine the type. So you example will return `double` as the type of `z` if running with Dart VM.

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print(1.1.runtimeType); // dartpad: double, dartvm: double
  print(1.0.runtimeType); // dartpad: int, dartvm: double
  print(1.runtimeType);   // dartpad: int, dartvm: int
}
```

See also the note about the different behavior of the `int` type, when compiled to JavaScript, in the Dart documentation:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.3/dart-core/int-class.html

A more detailed example is showed here where we can see how a `double` declared variable behave differently when running the Dart code in DartVM vs as compiled JavaScript:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print('| toString | runtimeType | is int | is double |');

  for (double i = 0; i <= 2; i += 0.5) {
    print('| ${i.toString().padRight(8)} | '
        '${i.runtimeType.toString().padLeft(11)} | '
        '${(i is int).toString().padLeft(6)} | '
        '${(i is double).toString().padLeft(9)} |');
  }
}
```

Which returns the following using DartPad:

```
| toString | runtimeType | is int | is double |
| 0        |         int |   true |      true |
| 0.5      |      double |  false |      true |
| 1        |         int |   true |      true |
| 1.5      |      double |  false |      true |
| 2        |         int |   true |      true |
```

While DartVM returns:

```
| toString | runtimeType | is int | is double |
| 0.0      |      double |  false |      true |
| 0.5      |      double |  false |      true |
| 1.0      |      double |  false |      true |
| 1.5      |      double |  false |      true |
| 2.0      |      double |  false |      true |
```

And for `int` we can do the same:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print('| toString | runtimeType | is int | is double |');

  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i += 1) {
    print('| ${i.toString().padRight(8)} | '
        '${i.runtimeType.toString().padLeft(11)} | '
        '${(i is int).toString().padLeft(6)} | '
        '${(i is double).toString().padLeft(9)} |');
  }
}
```

DartPad:

```
| toString | runtimeType | is int | is double |
| 0        |         int |   true |      true |
| 1        |         int |   true |      true |
| 2        |         int |   true |      true |
```

DartVM:

```
| toString | runtimeType | is int | is double |
| 0        |         int |   true |     false |
| 1        |         int |   true |     false |
| 2        |         int |   true |     false |
```

Comment: You say JavaScript represents all numbers as double internally then in all your examples the type on dartpad should be double but that's not the case.

Comment: I am saying that `runtimeType` are guessing what the type would be if it was normal Dart code. This is because you have some expectations (as the programmer) about types when you program in Dart. E.g. you are expecting a `int` when adding two `int` objects. But behind the scene, all numbers are always `double` in JavaScript.

Comment: One way to look at it is to say that *all* Dart numbers are `double`s when compiled to JavaScript, but *some* of them are *also* `int`s. It is as if the number object fori `1` implements both `int` and `double` at the same time (luckily, the interfaces are compatible). If you check `1 is double` or `1 is int`, both will give `true`. The `runtimeType` getter has to lie, there is no real class implementing both types, so it returns `int` when possible and `double` when not. In practice *never use `runtimeType` for anything!*

Comment: @lrn Oh yes, forgot about this. Updated the example to add some of your details to the example. And yes "never use `runtimeType` for anything!" cannot be said too often (maybe some day this warning is added to the API documentation?) :)