# Dart double "bitwise not" is giving different result (~~-1 != -1)

Tags: dart, bit-manipulation

So I am running dart on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/) And I tried running the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(~0);
  print(~-1);
  print(~~-1);
}
```

Which resulted in the following outputs

```
4294967295
0
4294967295
```

As you can see inverting the bits from 0 results in the max number (I was expecting -1 as dart uses two's complement) and inverting from -1 results in 0, which creates the situation where inverting 2 times -1 does not give me -1.

Looks like it's ignoring the first bit when inverting 0, why is that?

Comment: Might just be a DartPad thing. Here's another Dart interpreter's output: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0NToZpLQaGgKDOvRKPOQNMawdE1ROZBuLX//wMA "Dart – Try It Online")

Comment: In fact, numbers in DartPad seem broken in general? I don't really know Dart too well, but `9007199254740991 + 2` should give `9007199254740993` because it should represent 64-bit integers, but in DartPad it gives `9007199254740992` which is what JS would do with its limited precision.

Comment: The problem is that DartPad runs your code as compiled JavaScript and JavaScript represent all numbers as the type `double`. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741250/a-dart-code-behaves-differently-in-dartpad-and-local-because-of-double-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A dart code behaves differently in dartpad and local because of double type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741250/a-dart-code-behaves-differently-in-dartpad-and-local-because-of-double-type)

Comment: If you want 32- or 64-bit numbers that are portable across the Dart VM and Dart for the Web, you can use [`package:fixnum`](https://pub.dev/packages/fixnum), although that will sacrifice some speed.

Comment: @julemand101 I understood that the number is represented as a double, but shouldn't this behavior still be weird with doubles? Because inside js I can run `~~-1` and still get `-1`. Or is this a problem when dart interprets the double as a int?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz So the interpreter you sent isn't compiling to js? Or is it really a DartPad problem and not a problem from compiling to js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart compiled for the web (which includes DartPad) uses JavaScript numbers and number operations.
One of the consequences of that is that *bitwise* operations (`~`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`, `>>` and `>>>` on `int`) only gives 32-bit results, because that's what the corresponding JavaScript operations do.

For historical reasons, Dart chooses to give *unsigned* 32-bit results, not two's complement numbers. So `~-1` is 0 and `~0` is the unsigned `0xFFFFFFFF`, not -1.

In short, that's just how it is.